# How do I convert a byte to an array of eight booleans

Tags: java, arrays, binary, boolean, byte

I have a signed byte and I would like to convert it to an array of eight Boolean primitives in Java.

```
byte b = 64;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using BitSet to get the representation of the byte number...

## Example:

independently of the signed or not....

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte b1 = (byte) 129;
    BitSet bits = BitSet.valueOf(new byte[]{b1});
    System.out.println(bits); //
}
```